# jQuery UI sortable with body zoom not working, Not calculating drag and drop area correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to jQuery UI sortable work with zoom CSS property on body. But it's not allowing me to drag and drop correctly on the right position.

**Drag only working with half area, if user try to drag and drop from empty area on right side(Black area in my case) it's not working**

https://codepen.io/VijayDhanvai/pen/poqxEzQ

*Red area where drop not working*
[image: Red area where drop not working]

```
 $(function () {
    var zoomScale = $("body").css("zoom");
    console.log(typeof zoomScale, zoomScale.toString());
    var canvasHeight = $("#sortable").height();
    var canvasWidth = $("#sortable").width();

    $("#sortable").sortable({
      sort: function (e, ui) {
        var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
        var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
        var sortIndex =
          $("#sortable .ui-sortable-placeholder").index() + 30;
        var newLeft =
          ui.originalPosition.left +
          changeLeft / zoomScale -
          ui.item.parent().offset().left;

        var newTop =
          ui.originalPosition.top +
          changeTop / zoomScale -
          ui.item.parent().offset().top +
          sortIndex;

        ui.helper.css({
          left: newLeft,
          top: newTop,
        });
      },
    });
  });
```

```js
 $(function () {
        var zoomScale = $("body").css("zoom");
        console.log(typeof zoomScale, zoomScale.toString());
        var canvasHeight = $("#sortable").height();
        var canvasWidth = $("#sortable").width();

        $("#sortable").sortable({
          sort: function (e, ui) {
            var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
            var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
            var sortIndex =
              $("#sortable .ui-sortable-placeholder").index() + 30;
            var newLeft =
              ui.originalPosition.left +
              changeLeft / zoomScale -
              ui.item.parent().offset().left;

            var newTop =
              ui.originalPosition.top +
              changeTop / zoomScale -
              ui.item.parent().offset().top +
              sortIndex;

            ui.helper.css({
              left: newLeft,
              top: newTop,
            });
          },
        });
      });
```

```css
 .ui-sortable-placeholder,
      .ui-sortable-helper {
        visibility: visible !important;
        background-color: black !important;
      }
      .ui-sortable-placeholder td,
      .ui-sortable-helper td {
        background-color: aqua;
      }

      table {
        /* width: 100%; */
        border-spacing: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
      }
      td {
        padding: 0px;
        min-width: 100%;
        border: solid 1px #ddd;
      }
      body {
        zoom: 1.3;

        
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/borbit/jquery.viewport/raw/master/jquery.viewport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/borbit/jquery.scraggable/raw/master/jquery.scraggable.js"></script>

                  
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Month</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="sortable">
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$180</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I see no black area in your pen, could you please give some more explanation to your problem?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai  Updated Image

Comment: Add this 
```.ui-sortable-helper {
  background-color: aqua !important;
}```

Comment: @AdamBaranyai try to drag last row from empty right area, it would not allow dropping, but if you drag from text or from middle it allows dropping.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai did you get now what is issue ? Kindly check image again.

Comment: @GrzegorzT it's not an issue with background-color, it issues on applying zoom on body, drag and drop, not working from right sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possible Causes

The behavior of *jQuery UI* `sortable` is comparing the mouse position with the element offsets. However, It seems that offset values of children elements won't be affected by `zoom` if setting `zoom` on a parent element. ([Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW15) has mentioned it slightly.)

By the way, according to [Mozilla document of zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom), CSS `zoom` is non-standard. It means it has possibility of different behaviors in variable browsers. **If it's possible, try not to use CSS `zoom`.**

#### Solution: nested zooming

In your case, it works well to get the width after zooming if `zoom` set on `<td>`. So I try to set nested `zoom` to simulate the view of setting `zoom` on `<body>`:

```css
tbody {
  zoom: calc(1 / 1.3);
}

td {
  zoom: 1.3;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

body {
  zoom: 1.3;
}
```

If you do above, you don't have to calculate `helper` element by yourself:

```js
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

---

Here is demo: https://codepen.io/LyreneLiu/pen/PoXyQYx

Comment: you save my day, appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sortable use the draggable ui.https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').addClass('tddrag');
});
$(function () {
    var zoomScale = $("body").css("zoom");
    console.log(typeof zoomScale, zoomScale.toString());
    var canvasHeight = $(".sort").height();
    var canvasWidth = $(".sort").width();

    $(".tddrag").draggable({
        sort: function (e, ui) {
            var changeLeft = ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left;
            var changeTop = ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top;
            var sortIndex =  $(".sort .ui-sortable-placeholder").index() + 30;
            var newLeft =  ui.originalPosition.left + ( changeLeft / zoomScale - ui.item.parent().offset().left);
            var newTop =  ui.originalPosition.top + (changeTop / zoomScale -  ui.item.parent().offset().top) +  sortIndex;
            ui.helper.css({  
                left: newLeft,
                top: newTop,
            });
        },
    });
});
```